# Update of multipicklist field not working in SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I wrote the following class in salesforce:

```
global class ChangeImmo implements Schedulable{
 // Execute method
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<Realty_User__c> rs = [SELECT Buttons__c FROM Realty_User__c WHERE not (Buttons__c INCLUDES ('Terminplaner'))];
       for(Realty_User__c r : rs){
           r.Buttons__c += ';Terminplaner';
           update r;
       }                                                                           
    }
}
```

Then I sheduled it for a one time run.

It worked on our testbox, but not in the live version. We have 1700 users, of which around 730 don't have the "Terminplaner". Does someone know, why this is not working?

Edit: I adjusted my code with the guide on DML exceptions by SalesForce and it is still not working:

```
global class ChangeImmo implements Schedulable {

    // Execute method
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

        for (List < Realty_User__c > lstRu: [SELECT Buttons__c FROM Realty_User__c WHERE not(Buttons__c INCLUDES('Terminplaner'))]) {
            for (Realty_User__c r : lstRu) {
                r.Buttons__c += ';Terminplaner';
            }
            update lstRu;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Okay I have found the debug log now and the error says:

17:00:14.574 (10574150113)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 003b000000ZAhDgAAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

003 - it's a prefix of Contact object. Looks like you have some trigger in your production that work with contacts after you update Realty_User__c object.

Comment: Could you check a status of your scheduled jobs? If it failed - we can find some details /apexpages/setup/listAsyncApexJobs.apexp

Comment: Wait, I have to set up full debug log and see what it says, right now it is cutting of the relevant information!

Comment: 17:00:14.574 (10574150113)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 003b000000ZAhDgAAL
What does this mean?

Comment: 003 - it's a prefix of Contact object. Looks like you have some trigger in your production that work with contacts after you update Realty_User__c object.

Comment: So I can guess the mistake lies within the trigger, not inside my class?

Comment: Yep. Looks like problem not inside your class

Comment: If you would edit your answer in which you just say this sentence about the 003 prefix I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    global class ChangeImmo implements Schedulable{
```

// Execute method

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    List<Realty_User__c> rs = [SELECT Buttons__c FROM Realty_User__c WHERE not (Buttons__c INCLUDES ('Terminplaner'))];
   for(Realty_User__c r : rs){
       **r.Buttons__c += ';Terminplaner';**
       update r;
   }                                                                           
}
```

}

Seems you are not updating values.

ex:`r.Buttons__c += 'value1;value2;Terminplaner';
           update r;`

Comment: Hey, this is not the problem. As I wrote, it is working in the sandbox.